# How to set the default user column sort in Avalonia's DataGrid?

Tags: c#, avaloniaui, avalonia

Here is an example of what I'm looking to be able to set in code:

[image: The red box shows sorting applied to the column in descending order.]

Answer (score 1):

[This pull request](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/pull/6730/files) seems to indicate you can call this DataGridColumn method to apply a sort programmatically:

```
public void Sort(ListSortDirection direction)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to post an example, using the [answer from @DrunkenCodeMonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75065983/1997232) (upvote his answer).

Code behind:

```
public partial class SomeUserControlOrWindow: UserControl
{
    public SomeUserControlOrWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // set default sorting
        Dispatcher.UIThread.InvokeAsync(() =>
            this.FindControl<DataGrid>("dataGrid").Columns.First().Sort());
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        AvaloniaXamlLoader.Load(this);
    }
}
```

In view:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid" ...>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" .../>
        ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can, I would recommend doing the sort in code, and then using that to initially populate the table e.g. LINQ:

```
var orderByDescendingResult = from d in dataList
               orderby d.Id descending
               select d;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this can be done DataGrid.Columns[0].Sort(); and here is DataGrid.SelectedIndex = 0; does not work .

Comment: This _can_ be done? But it _doesn’t_ work? I’m confused. Can you clarify?

Comment: Your response is appreciated, but it appears that the solution you've provided might be a bit unclear or difficult to follow for most readers. Could you please consider revising your answer and providing more step-by-step explanations or examples? The goal is to make sure that the solution is accessible and understandable to everyone seeking assistance. Thank you for your contribution!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
    public async void load(object? sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Dispatcher.UIThread.InvokeAsync(() => this.list1?.Columns[0].Sort());
        await Dispatcher.UIThread.InvokeAsync(() => this.list1.SelectedIndex = 0);
        this.list1?.Focus();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

We should wait for DataGrid to apply the template.
Inside view we should do like this:
`<DataGrid TemplateApplied="OnDataGridTemplateApplied">`

Code behind:

```
    private void OnDataGridTemplateApplied(object? sender, TemplateAppliedEventArgs args)
    {
        var dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender!;
        dataGrid.Columns.First().Sort();
        dataGrid.TemplateApplied -= OnDataGridTemplateApplied;
    }
```